# connecting to mongodb with ipv6 via mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, ipv6, mongo-shell

I was able to enable ipv6 on mongodb.

```
/etc/mongod.conf file has net.ipv6 set to true.
```

I can see that mongodb is listening on ipv6:

```
# netstat -anp | grep 27017
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17967/mongod        
tcp6       0      0 :::27017                :::*                    LISTEN      17967/mongod        
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19750206 17967/mongod         /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
#
```

ping6 to the IPv6 address is fine.

```
[root@tesla05 log]# ping6 -I eno33554952 tesla05-2-ipv6.ulticom.com
PING tesla05-2-ipv6.ulticom.com(tesla05) from fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43 eno33554952: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from tesla05: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from tesla05: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
64 bytes from tesla05: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
```

however, mongo shell doesn't seem to understand ipv6 address.

```
[root@tesla05 log]# mongo --ipv6 [fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43]:27017/admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: [fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43]:27017/admin
2016-10-25T12:04:50.401-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43:27017, reason: errno:22 Invalid argument
2016-10-25T12:04:50.402-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server [fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43]:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

[root@tesla05 log]# mongo --ipv6 tesla05-2-ipv6.ulticom.com:27017/admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: tesla05-2-ipv6.ulticom.com:27017/admin
2016-10-25T12:15:17.861-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43:27017, reason: errno:22 Invalid argument
2016-10-25T12:15:17.861-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server tesla05-2-ipv6.ulticom.com:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use a link-local IPv6 address. These are not valid without a *scope*, but you haven't provided one. Thus you get the error `Invalid argument`. For this reason, putting a link-local address in the DNS makes no sense, because the address is only valid on a particular LAN, and the scope may be different for every host on that LAN.

To use the address, append the scope to it, e.g. `fe80::250:56ff:feb4:7c43%eno33554952`